# Complex JSON encoding with PHP PDO Object Oriented - arrays

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, pdo

I have a complex JSON file which I want to compile by using PDO. I'm pretty new to PDO and I'm having trouble forming good a PDO statement which places arrays within arrays which are coming from multiple tables. For example the "Bounds" are coming from a seperate db table called bounds. I would love to learn an Object Oriented solution of this problem. Can you help me and send me into learning the solution

The JSON file I want to create (its only the start of a much larger file):

```
[{
"map": {

    "name": "My Map",
    "description": "My map rules",
    "id": "id_1",
    "type": "size1",
    "activelayer": "layerid1",

    "bounds": {
        "tl": {
            "latitude": "51.96584631886286",
            "longitude": "4.316253662109375"
        },
        "br": {
            "latitude": "51.89386778172307",
            "longitude": "4.433155059814453"
        }
    },

    "zoom": {
        "start": "14",
        "min": "0",
        "max": "4"
    },

    "mainlayers": [
        {

            "id": "layerid1",
            "name": "Layer 1",

            "sublayers": [
                {
                    "id": "sublayer_1"
                }, {
                    "id": "sublayer_2"
                }
            ]
```

-->end here for this example

Currently I got a good, safe connection which can be called from

```
$pdo=database::connect();
```

Comment: Instead of showing the connection line (which is meaningless in the question's context), you'd better show the DB structure.

Answer (score 2):

## PDO has absolutely nothing to do with JSON

So, instead of "forming good a PDO statement" you have

1. Form a regular **SQL** statement to retrieve required data.
2. Run it against database using PDO to get plain 2-dimensional array.
3. **Write a PHP program** to process the above array into whatever structure you need
4. Finally, call `json_encode()` to encode it.

Comment: Hi, I think I formed the question in a wrong way.

Comment: @Gkar2000 most likely. Anyway, there should be no PDO involved in it. Assume you have an array of data from unknown source which is unimportant.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, What I am trying to do is start with the JSON output above, using this I want to form a PHP process and a database which would lead to the above output.